# Shell Script Find and Copy from txt file

Tags: macos, shell, sh

I'm wanting to read line by line from a text file to recursively find files in a target folder. If found copy that file to another directory. The script below executes but doesn't perform the find or copy when running `sh script.sh` from terminal. No errors are displayed, it will echo the `$line` variable string correctly for each loop iteration. Running the same `find` from terminal using an actual filename instead of the `$list` variable does complete the task successfully.

Script:

```
script.sh
#!/bin/bash
file="filenames.txt"
while IFS= read line
do
find /Volumes/share/all-files-location -name "$line" -print -exec cp {} /Volumes/share/found-files-location \;
done < "$file"
```

List of file names, plain text:

```
A1037_MG_1262.jpg
A1037_MG_12621.jpg
A1037_MG_1263.jpg
[11,000 more entries]
```

Thoughts?

Comment: This seems to work fine on my machine, adjusting the paths and filenames to things that actually exist on my boot drive. Are you sure that all the paths are correct?

Comment: Also, do the paths to any of the files in question contain spaces or other unusual characters?

Comment: No space in the files that are intended to be copied. Adjusting my script to "find ~/Desktop/test-folder/all-web-photos -name "$line" -print -exec cp {} ~/Desktop/test-folder/found \;" doesn't work either, again no errors. Running the find command with a file name rather than a variable in the terminal window does perform correctly so my paths are surely correct.

Comment: What line ending does the input file use? CR, LF, CRLF?

Comment: The input file uses CRLF

Comment: Ugh. I switched it to LF and it immediately fixed my problem. Thanks. Love you long time!

Comment: Great! I'm going to rewrite it as an answer; please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the input file was in CRLF, and Unix generally uses LF as its line ending, the bash script was sorting the lines by the occurrence of the LF character, and consequently each of your filenames had `\r` appended to the end of it. Since your disk probably didn't contain filenames containing `\r`, the `find` tool didn't find any of the files, the result being that your tool appeared to fail with no error message given.

Solution: Switch the file's line ending format to LF.